# Alternate to PHP exec() function

Tags: php, exec, zcat

Currently I am using:

```
exec("zcat $filename", $output)
```

To uncompress a `.Z` type file but unfortunately my hosting company has now disabled this function.

Is there a workaround?

```
$pathtofile = "filename.lis.Z";
exec("zcat $pathtofile", $output);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the `compress` format `.Z` is not understood by zlib itself, so PHPs `gzuncompress()` won't work. If you can't use `exec` anymore, you'll have to adapt your file sources. Use `gzip` from now on.

Comment: Unfortunately the files I am fetching are in .Z format. Unless there is an automatic way of converting them to gzip format I have to stick with .Z format. Do you know any host which allows exec() ?

Comment: Well, practically any professional hoster is using suexec rather than the safemode workaround. Note that your `zcat` was a special version with .Z support; you might need to reinstall that or use `uncompress -c $filename` rather. Also remember `escapeshellarg()` here.

Comment: I haven't used escapeshellarg() but php.net help file says "Escape a string to be used as a shell argument" but the issue is i think in order to use it i still need system() or exec() but my hosting has blocked both. Do you know any service provide who might not give me such nightmares?

Comment: @mario how to use suexec? My hosting company told me that they have installed suexec but i can't still use exec() function so wondering how does it work now?

Comment: Has nothing do to with each other (suexec is a server setting, not a php function). Change your hoster.

Comment: Dam! I can't find a host which is offering exec() i have tried searching for one even on google but no success so far

Comment: Just get a basic unmanaged VPS for $5/month and set up the stack yourself, and you won't have to worry about what the host disables.

Answer (score 12):

do this

```
echo ini_get("disable_functions");
```

to know if you are able to use one of the following:

`system();`
`exec();`
`passthru();`
`shell_exec();`

but if it's a shared hosting all the above are for sure blocked and you will have to find an alternative

Comment: show_source, system, shell_exec, passthru, exec, popen, proc_open, chmod, mkdir, chdir,allow_url_fopen,rmdir

Answer (score 5):

.Z files are [LZW compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch). If you can't run shell commands on your host, you can use an LZW PHP library. Here are two:

- [web wonders](http://webdevwonders.com/lzw-compression-and-decompression-with-javascript-and-php/)
- [php-lzw](http://code.google.com/p/php-lzw/)

Answer (score 3):

```
system($shell_command, $response_var);
```

So in your case:

```
system("zcat $filename", $output);
```

Comment: i can almost bet that they blocked this and passthru() too

Comment: im sure they did too lol, just throwing out alternative methods

Comment: they have disabled system() too

Comment: Yea figures, you need to call them and explain your situation. if they aren't interested in re-configuring anything for you, then you need to switch hosts.

Comment: Well I tried calling them and didn't help since they aren't interested in re-configuring. Any recommendations as to which host might allow using exec() ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, disabled commands are

```
dl
sh2_exec
diskfreespace
disk_free_space
disk_total_space
escapeshellarg
escapeshellcmd
exec
highlight_file
link
lchgrp
lchown
passthru
pclose
popen
proc_close
proc_get_status
proc_nice
proc_open
proc_terminate
set_time_limit
shell_exec
show_source
symlink
system
mail
sendmail
```

So if one of those commands not blocked in your side, you may find a way to execute command.