# PHP execute function instead of Shell execute functions

Tags: php

I need to run function on my server

```
exec('grep '.escapeshellarg($line).' '.$myFile)
```

But `exec` is disabled for security reasons
But PHP execute function is working `eval` and `preg_replace`.

It is possible to do the same thing using php function?

Disabled function

> link, symlink, exec, passthru, proc_close, proc_get_status, proc_open,
>   shell_exec, system, popen, pclose

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565081/alternate-to-php-exec-function) to check out if you can use any of the other functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All php functions able to execute command in shell are disabled in your server. So forget about exec family of functions.You need to open file and check for the pattern.

```
$file = file_get_contents ($myFile);
preg_match_all ($line, $file, $matches);
print_r ($matches);
```