# How to extract multi-part zip files using PHP?

Tags: php, unzip

I used this code {from : [Unzip a file with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889025/unzip-a-file-with-php)}

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('file.zip');
if ($res === TRUE) {
  $zip->extractTo('/myzips/extract_path/');
  $zip->close();
  echo 'woot!';
} else {
  echo 'doh!';
}
```

but it doesn't work with multi-part zip files.
The names of my files are

```
file.zip
file.z01
file.z02 
This's for example :)
```

*Note  : I can't run shell commands because I use shared hosting {[Alternate to PHP exec() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565081/alternate-to-php-exec-function)}

Comment: To my knowledge `ZipArchive` in PHP can make multi-part zip files, but I don't think it has the ability to open one. I would say use the shell, but you've excluded that option. Another option is to simulate linux `cat` with PHP so it merges all files into one file, then it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Xorifelse Ok, reopened

Comment: @Xorifelse How can I do that ? Does it work in shared hosting? Do you have any link to be my guide? Sorry, because I am beginner and English isn't my tongue...

Comment: Gotta be honest here, I've looked around a bit couldn't find a direct solution other then merging the files to one file using cat. The [source code of Linux cat](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/plain/src/cat.c). I didn't see a PHP function of it in the short while I looked (doesn't mean there isn't any), so.. trial and error and start scripting! (only focus on the part that doesn't use options/modifiers) (or move web host).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it... In my case, I had, say:

- file.zip.001
- ...
- file.zip.006

This setup was a result of running the command `7z a -tzip -v5M Split/file file.zip`, which basically just split the file up into concatenate-able files of about 5M in size...

This code merged them together, special thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23932025/1599699) for some help:

```php
<?php

for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; ++$i)
{
  $content = file_get_contents("file.zip.00" . $i);
  file_put_contents("file.zip", $content, FILE_APPEND);
}

echo "Merged! Make sure to delete...";

?>
```

Obviously, make sure "file.zip" doesn't exist or is empty beforehand...

Then, to unzip it, I ran this:

```php
<?php

$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open("file.zip") === TRUE)
{
  $zip->extractTo("folder/");
  $zip->close();
  echo "Unzipped!";
}
else
{
  echo "Failed...";
}

?>
```